# Jasmine - spyOn constructor method

Tags: javascript, jasmine

For the following code:

```
class Endpoint {
  constructor(type, start_value) {
    this.type = type
    this.end_value = start_value + 2
    this.constructor.prefill(type, this.end_value)
  }
  static prefill(type, end_value) {
    console.log("called")
    $("#end_value").text(end_value)
  }
}
```

The following spec is failing (the spy was NOT called, i.e., a `.not.toHaveBeenCalled()` passes), even though I can confirm via the `console.log` output and the DOM `$("#end_value")` being filled correctly that the call is happening.

```
describe("when constructing end point class", function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    endpoint = new Endpoint("typeA", 3)
    spyOn(endpoint.constructor, "prefill")
  })
  it("calls prefill", function() {
    expect(endpoint.constructor.prefill).toHaveBeenCalledWith("typeA", 5)
  })
})
```

Using the following

```
jasmine (2.7.0)
jasmine-core (2.8.0)
jasmine-jquery-rails (2.0.3)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Timing matters here for the spy set-up. Initializing the class calls the constructor. The spy missed the call because it was set-up *after* creating a new instance, try switching the order ([plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/HBhNwn?p=preview)):

```
import { Endpoint } from './endpoint';

describe("when constructing end point class", function() {

  let endpoint;

  beforeEach(function() {
    spyOn(Endpoint, "prefill"); // add spy before initializing class
    endpoint = new Endpoint("typeA", 3);
  })
  it("calls prefill", function() {
    expect(Endpoint.prefill).toHaveBeenCalledWith("typeA", 5);
  })
});
```

Sidenote: I haven't seen `this.constructor.myStaticMethod` syntax before, usually static methods are invoked from the class definition: `Endpoint.prefill(param1, param2)`. Test passed with either invocation style but I'd be curious to understand the choice there.

Comment: updated answer and added a plunker for you to play with

Comment: ah this works! `this.constructor.prefill` is the same as saying `Endpoint.prefill` since `this.constructor` is a reference to the class itself. that's my undersatnding! Indeed, the test passes even if you mix up the spy and expectation (i.e., use `endpoint.constructor` vs `Endpoint` interchangeably). I wrote it this way to be more explicit that prefill is a method on the actual class